# Collector mistake with Discord bot in JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm doing a quizz with some questions:

```
const questions = [
  {
    question: "What is the capital of France?",
    answer: "Paris",
  },
  {
    question: "Who is the best barcelona player of all history?",
    answer: "Messi",
  },
];
```

What works: When the user have the correct answer, the next question is show up and when all the questions are displayed, the quizz is finish

What is the problem: The user have 10 seconds for give a answer. So if nobody have the correct answer in 10 answer, the next question is displayed.So currently, nothing happened in 10 seconds and it's block to the same question.

This is my script:

```
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
//...

const handleQuestion = () => {
if (i >= questions.length) {
  return;
}
channel.send(questions[i].question);

// Create a collector to get the answers from users
const filter = m => !m.author.bot;
const collector = channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { time: 10000 });

collector.on('collect', message => {
  if (message.content === questions[i].answer) {
    channel.send(`${message.author} a trouvé la bonne réponse!`);
    collector.stop();
  }
});

collector.on('end', collected => {
  i++;
  if (i >= questions.length) {
    channel.send('Toutes les questions ont été posées!');
    return;
  }
  if (!collected.size) {
    channel.send(`Aucune réponse n'a été trouvée pour la question "${questions[i].question}"`);
  }
  handleQuestion();
});
};

handleQuestion();
}
});

client.login('Token_discord');
```

Comment: What's your discord.js version?

Comment: "discord.js": "^14.7.1",

Comment: Thanks, you'll need to update `channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { time: 10000 })` to `channel.createMessageCollector({ filter, time: 10000 })`

Comment: Thank you for your help, appreciate. I'm sorry for the duplicaiton